# Should we burninate the [code-shuffleboard] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This tag only has 2 questions using it, and I don't think it's that great of a challenge type, since it is vague and encourages no-ops. It also ends up being a popularity contest.

Overall, I think the tag is bland and useless, so we might as well remove it.

Challenges tagged [code-shuffleboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-shuffleboard):

- [Hello World in 1024 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8859/hello-world-in-1024-characters) (currently has some close votes)
- [Maximizing output from minimal input](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67255/maximizing-output-from-minimal-input)

The tag's usage in the meta:

- [New puzzle type: code-shuffleboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/new-puzzle-type-code-shuffleboard)
- [Make the criteria tags obligatory](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/make-the-criteria-tags-obligatory)
- [The Tag Categorization Project](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/the-tag-categorization-project/908?s=5|0.0855#908)

Comment: Well, there's probably actually a lot more challenges of this type, just without the tag. My [Predict whether a message will be starred or not in 50 bytes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69584/3808), for example.

Comment: Also the Mona Lisa in 4 kb is arguably code-shuffleboard

Answer (score 5):

Tags denoting challenge types should only be removed if

1. that challenge type is deemed off topic by community consensus, and
2. there aren't too many to retag.

In this case we have #2 but not #1. If we're going to remove the [code-shuffleboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-shuffleboard) tag, we should either discuss whether that challenge type should be made off topic, merged with [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), or something else.

Answer (score 2):

The tag name is quite undescriptive, so I suggest removing or renaming the tag:

- If the tag is removed, I think these challenges would still fit under [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) as we basically have a length restriction on the source code.
- Otherwise I suggest renaming it to something like [restricted-size](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-size)

Comment: I agree, restricted source is a much better fit